# Certificate based authentication on internet facing secure site

Tags: webserver, ssl-certificate, client-certificates, pki

I have to develop a web application that is both secured over https and uses client authentication certificates. The clients are connecting via invitation, thus it is not intended for users stumbling upon this application by googling around.

The ideal would be to get an intermediate CA certificate form a public root authority and sign both the ssl certificate and use it to issue client authentication certificates. I think that won't work, as simply put I will never qualify for such an intermediate CA (as far as I know, but maybe I am wrong with that).

Second guess: create own Root CA, an intermediate CA and use them. Because of what I wrote about the users, I can embed the necessary certificate chain in the issued certificates. This technically works.

What I would prefer is to get an ssl certificate from public authority *and* to use my own chain to issue authentication certificates and verify the users. According to [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/sy10670_.htm) it is possible. But I haven't found anything about how to configure IIS for example (or Kestrel) to request client certificates issued by a specific CA, even less some standard specification where this flow is described.

Comment: IIS (and most likely kestrel too) will send list of trusted CA from LocalMachine\Root store to the client when negotiating TLS channel. If you place your custom rootCA in server's root store you will be able to authenticate. No intermediate CA is needed. Of course place the rootCA in client's root store as well.

Comment: Thank you @pepo, this looks promising!